# Improving run time for R with nested for loops

Tags: r, runtime, apply

My reproducible R example:

```
f = runif(1500,10,50)
p = matrix(0, nrow=1250, ncol=250)
count = rep(0, 1250)
for(i in 1:1250) {
    ref=f[i]
    for(j in 1:250) {
        p[i,j] = f[i + j - 1] / ref-1
        if(p[i,j] == "NaN") {
           count[i] = count[i]
           }
        else if(p[i,j] > (0.026)) {
                count[i] = (count[i] + 1) 
                ref = f[i + j - 1] 
                } 
        } 
    }
```

To be more precise, I have a set of 600 f-series and this code runs 200 times for each f-series. Currently I am doing the iterations in loops and most of the operations are element-wise. My random variables are `f`, the condition `if(p[i,j] > (0.026))`, and the number `0.026` in itself.

One can drastically reduce the run-time by vectorizing my code and using functions, specifically the apply family, but I am rusty with apply and looking for some advice to proceed in the right direction.

Comment: Right, wouldn't use `c=rep(0,1250)` since c is the useful concatenation function in R.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are using a vector of random uniform variables to generate a matrix with some kind of peculiar correlation structure. Because through each iteration, code requires the values calculated from a previous iteration, your iterations are not independent. You cannot vectorize this code. However if you can better describe what results you are trying to achieve, there may be better methods of achieving your desired output.

Comment: Edited as per suggestions.

Comment: Vlo, I can't change the algorithm steps as they are predetermined, and not the smartest of logic. I can hoping that converting this code into a function and then "applying" it over a dataframe of 600 f-series might make the code run faster instead of the for loops I am using right now. Do you think that assumption is correct?

Comment: As @Vlo states, you have an iterative dependency that you will not be able to address with vectorization or `*apply` (note `*apply` is no faster than a `for` loop when the `for` loop is pre-allocated as you do here).  As Khashaa suggests, RCPP might be your best route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ajmartin, your logic was better and reduced the number of iterations I was attempting. Here is the improved version of your code in R:

```
f1 <- function() {
  n <- 1500
  d <- 250
  f = runif(n,1,5)
  count = rep(0, n-d)
  for(i in 1:(n-d)) {
    tem <- f[i:(i+d-1)] / f[i] - 1
    ind = which(tem>0.026)[1]
    while(length(which(tem>0.026))){
      count[i] = count[i] + 1
      tem[ind:d] = f[ind:d] / tem[ind] - 1
      ind = ind - 1 + (which(tem[ind:d] > 0.026)[1])
    }
  }
  list(f, count)
}

system.time(f1())[3]
# elapsed 
#    0.09
```

Implementing this in Rcpp will further reduce system-time but I can't install Rtools as my current machine does not have admin rights. Meanwhile this helps.

Answer (score 4):

It is [quite easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618610/how-to-make-function-perform-faster/28620014#28620014) to put `for loop`s in Rcpp. I just copy-pasted your code to Rcpp and haven't checked the validity. In case of discrepancy, let me know. `fCpp` returns the list of `p` and `c`.

```
cppFunction('List fCpp(NumericVector f) {
    const int n=1250; 
            const int k=250;
            NumericMatrix p(n, k);
            NumericVector c(n);

            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            double ref=f[i];
            for(int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            p(i,j) = f[i+j+1]/ref-1;
            if(p(i,j) == NAN){
            c[i]=c[i];
            }
            else if(p(i,j) > 0.026){
            c[i] = c[i]+1; 
            ref = f[i+j+1]; 
            } 
            }
            }
            return List::create(p, c);
            }')
```

**Benchmark**

```
set.seed(1)
f = runif(1500,10,50)

f1 <- function(f){
    p = matrix(0, nrow=1250, ncol=250)
    count = rep(0, 1250)
    for(i in 1:1250) {
        ref=f[i]
        for(j in 1:250) {
            p[i,j] = f[i + j - 1] / ref-1
            if(p[i,j] == "NaN") {
                count[i] = count[i]
            }
            else if(p[i,j] > (0.026)) {
                count[i] = (count[i] + 1) 
                ref = f[i + j - 1] 
            } 
        } 
    }
    list(p, count)
}


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fCpp(f), f1(f), times=10L, unit="relative")
Unit: relative
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 fCpp(f)   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000    10
   f1(f) 785.8484 753.7044 734.4243 764.5883 718.0868 644.9022    10
```

Values returned by `fCpp(f)` and `f1(f)` are essentially identical, apart from column 1 of `p` matrix returned by `f1` is filled with 0s.

```
system.time(a <- f1(f))[3]
#elapsed 
#    2.8 
system.time(a1 <- fCpp(f))[3]
#elapsed 
#      0 
all.equal( a[[1]], a1[[1]])
#[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.7019406"
all.equal( a[[2]], a1[[2]])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Just curious if you have the code easily available, how do the two version benchmark?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation using `while`, although it is taking much longer than nested `for` loops which is a bit counter intuitive.

```
f1 <- function() {
    n <- 1500
    d <- 250
    f = runif(n,1,5)
    f = embed(f, d)
    f = f[-(n-d+1),]
    count = rep(0, n-d)
    for(i in 1:(n-d)) {
        tem <- f[i,]/f[i,1] - 1
        ti <- which(t[-d] > 0.026)[1]
        while(ti < d & !is.na(ti)) {
            ti.plus = ti+1
            tem[ti.plus:d] = f[i, ti.plus:d] / tem[ti]
            count[i] = count[i] + 1
            ti <- ti + which(tem[ti.plus:d-1] > 0.026)[1]
        }
        f[i] = tem
    }
    list(f, count)
}

system.time(f1())

#elapsed 
#6.365
```

Comment: Your code is slow due to the use of `embed` and `is.na` in the `while` condition. Also, I have improved the implementation a little to further increase efficiency.