# Extracting result from a for loop inside while loop - r

Tags: r

I'm not that used to writing `while` loops in R.  Wonder if anyone could show me how to get the first result of `i` from this simplified version:

I've tried doing it storing the `i` as a vector.

Essentially, I want to know the first number from 1 to 100 for which

(z - i) / 10 is less than 9

```
z <- 100
p <- z/10
myi <- NULL

while(p>=9){

  for(i in 1:100){
    myi[[i]] <- i
    p <- (z-i)/10
  }
break()
}
```

When this breaks, p=0 and I'm not sure why.  What I want to return is 11, i.e. the first instance where (z-1)/10 is not greater than or equal to 9.

If I return `myi` it just shows every number from 1 to 100.  Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I'm interested in other fast approaches to this question - the following is the fastest I can work out:

`which.max(sapply(seq_along(1:100), function(x) (z-x)/10 < 9))`

but still would like to work out how to do this using the `while` loop

Comment: The for-loop will always complete if starts. (And do not use comments to edit your questions. The edit link is there for a purpose.) If you wnat to break out of a for-loop you need to put that as an if-conditional test with `break()` as a consequent.

Comment: Based on the edit, perhaps `tail(which(((z-1:100)/10 ) >= 9),1)+1#[1] 11`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 general ways of accomplishing this task with a `while` loop. The first is to test for the condition you want in the while loop's condition statement, as in:

```
#initialize i
i = 1
while((z-i)/10 < 9)# test for the condition of interest 
    # incremenet i
    i = i + 1
```

And the second is to use a `while(TRUE)` loop, and to test for the condition in the body of the while loop and break out of the loop if the condition is met, as in:

```
#initialize i
i = 1
while(TRUE) {
    # test for the condition of interest
    if((z-i)/10 < 9)
        # break if the condition is met
        break
    # incremenet i
    i = i + 1
}
```

in both of these solutions `i` is the first value that meets your condition. Also notice that `break` is used as a keyword and not a function call.

Also probably the only way to get much faster than this solution is to implement it C++ as in the accepted response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618610/how-to-make-function-perform-faster).